# How to update SQLAlchemy Postgres array at a single element?

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

There is no docs for ARRAY field update in sqlalchemy. Idk, how to update position by index in sqlachemy orm. There is only possible to update the whole array, but I need to update single element in entry.

I found example in postgres docs:

```sql
SELECT * FROM sal_emp;
 name  |      pay_by_quarter       |                 schedule
-------+---------------------------+-------------------------------------------
 Bill  | {10000,10000,10000,10000} | {{meeting,lunch},{training,presentation}}
 Carol | {20000,25000,25000,25000} | {{breakfast,consulting},{meeting,lunch}}
```

```sql
UPDATE sal_emp SET pay_by_quarter[4] = 15000
WHERE name = 'Bill';
```

But I didn't find how to slice or index in `.values` method, there is only keyword arguments supported.

```py
# sqlalchemy

update(SalEmp).values(pay_by_quarter=???).where(SalEmp.name=='Bill')

# Can't do like this:

update(SalEmp).values(SalEmp.pay_by_quarter[4]=15000).where(SalEmp.name=='Bill')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by passing a dict such as `{SalEmp.pay_by_quarter[4]: 15000}` to `values`.

The ORM query looks like

`update(SalEmp).values({SalEmp.pay_by_quarter[4]: 15000}).where(SalEmp.name=='Bill')`

Comment: The output looks very strange in database
`{10000}` -> `[0:1]={15000,10000}`


Somehow, this query generates a slice:


 `q.compile(dialect=postgresql.dialect(), compile_kwargs={"literal_binds": True})` 

returns `UPDATE "sal_emp" SET pay_by_quarter[%(pay_by_quarter_1)s::VARCHAR[]]='15000'`

I use `ARRAY[str]` in my project

Comment: @Mastermind if you are not aware, postgres array index starts at 1, with that being said, using a zero based index would cause a slice I guess, can you try with a one based index?

Comment: Thx a lot, adding +1 to from-python index, worked!